# Bets way to remotely connect to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tightvncserver

I have been trying all day to connect to Ubuntu 18.04 suing VNC.

I have seen quite a few approaches where vino is started up using Startup Applications however I want the vncserver to startup on boot and not when a user logs in.

I have tried tightvncserver and tigervncserver however no success.

I set the same up on RHEL7 in around 20 minutes on Friday and Solaris 10.

Comment: You could have a look at x2go. It is based on NX and provides a complete remote desktop or single remote app. It is tunneled through SSH, so no need to open additional ports in firewall.

Comment: yeah might have to look at something else. Is there really no way of gettting vinoserver to run as  daemon without requiring a user log on .